# Rspec user input while loop tests

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am using RSpec to test my rock paper scissors game. Included in my `begin_game` function I have the following code:

```
user_input = gets.chomp.downcase.to_sym
while !choices.include? user_input
  puts "Please choose a valid selection : rock, paper, or scissors"
  user_input = gets.chomp.downcase.to_sym
end
```

I am trying to test for different possible user_inputs. I have tried this:

```
let(:new_game) {RockPaperScissors.new}
.......
context 'validate that the user input is one of the given choices' do
  it 'should prompt the user for a new input if the original one is invalid' do
  new_game.stub(:gets) {"r"}
  expect(new_game.begin_game).to eq("Please choose a valid selection : rock, paper, or scissors")
  end
end
```

but this results in an infinite loop of "Please choose a valid selection ..." being outputted to Terminal. I read the RSpec mocking documentation but it was difficult for me to understand.

Comment: I think you should be doing `STDIN.stub(:gets)` or `Kernel.stub(:gets)` instead of `new_game.stub`

Answer (score 3):

The reason why it's looping is because `new_game.stub(:gets) { "r" }` will always return `r` no matter how many times you call it. Thus `user_input` will never contain valid input and your test will run forever.

To fix this, you should make `new_game#gets` return a valid selection after a certain number of tries.

For example,

```
new_game.stub(:gets) do
  @counter ||= 0
  response = if @counter > 3 # an arbitrary threshold
               "rock"
             else
               "r"
             end
  @counter += 1
  response
end
```

This would cause your test to print `Please choose a valid selection...` 4 times and then terminate.

Depending on how you implemented `RockPaperScissors#begin_game`, the test you wrote would still not pass. This is because `puts("a string")` will always return `nil`. Moreover, a `while` loop will also return `nil`. So at no point would the above snippet of code return the string `"Please choose a valid selection : rock, paper, or scissors"`.

An implementation of `begin_game` that would pass is:

```
def begin_game
  user_input = gets.chomp.downcase.to_sym
  if choices.include? user_input
    # return something here
  else
    "Please choose a valid selection : rock, paper, or scissors"
  end
end
```

but at that point, I would probably rename it to `handle_move`, and have it accept an argument as a parameter to avoid stubbing `gets` in the first place.

```
def handle_move(input)
  if choices.include? input
    "Great move!"
  else
    "Please choose a valid selection : rock, paper, or scissors"
  end
end
```

Comment: I just used a variation on this idea to test a related situation.  It was really helpful.  Thanks!